# Perl local::lib boostrap getting stuck

Tags: perl, locallib

I attempted the installation for `local::lib` (I have no trouble installing the `ExeUtils::MakeMaker` pre-requisite).

I found the command from here: [https://metacpan.org/pod/local::lib](https://metacpan.org/pod/local%3a%3alib)

```
[frank@simunec1 local-lib-1.008010]$ perl Makefile.PL --bootstrap
Attempting to create directory /home1/frank/perl5
*** Module::AutoInstall version 1.06
*** Checking for Perl dependencies...
[Core Features]
- ExtUtils::MakeMaker ...loaded. (6.68 >= 6.31)
- ExtUtils::Install   ...loaded. (1.54 >= 1.43)
- Module::Build       ...loaded. (0.3601 >= 0.36)
- CPAN                ...loaded. (1.9402 >= 1.82)
*** Module::AutoInstall configuration finished.
Writing Makefile for local::lib
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
**<Stuck for 15 minutes>**
```

I have also tried to run this command and pointing it to another user directory that I have access to, but it still gets stuck.
ie. perl `Makefile.PL` `--bootstrap=/nas1_home4/frank/perllibrary`

I don't expect it would take 15+ minutes to write a makefile for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that while it gets stuck, if you do a Ctrl+C.  The Makefile is still generated.  Afterwards, running make, and then make test passes.  make install works fine as well.  It is weird that it is stuck, but hope this finding helps someone.